# Another implicit token error - how to tweak definitions to address it

Tags: antlr, grammar, dsl, antlr4

I am aware what implicit token definition error in parser means, but am having difficulty getting rid of it. (v4)

stripped down statements:
enum_decl  : GTYPE_ENUM ID LSQUARE STRING STRING* RSQUARE SEMI ;
string_decl: GTYPE_STRING ID (COMMA ID)* SEMI ;

In string_decl, that error appears on SEMI
In enum_decl the same error is on RSQUARE
GTYPE_ENUM, ID, etc. all are defined / accepted correctly, in the Lexer section.

Comment: It's better to edit the question instead of updating the question in a comment to an answer, because 1) it's easier to find for others and 2) you can easily insert code snippets by indenting them with 4 spaces. Apart from that your sample doesn't reproduce the error you asked for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you type in that little tiny section trying to find a small test case that doesn't work? Without a grammar to test there's nothing we can do.  Is either a bug or a problem with your grammar.

Comment: Fair enough!!... am fleshing out the grammar a bit more to be able to create better/longer samples and I will either come back to this question or repost, if I still see the yellow squiggly under SEMICOLON etc. in antlrworks.

Comment: in antlrworks, grammar is: `grammar VDevCfg;

// parser

module: 
    GRMR_START
        module_content
    GRMR_END ;

module_content: 
    file_type_decl ;

file_type_decl   : GTYPE_FILE FILE_TYPE SEMICOLON ;

// Lexer

GRMR_START  : '!g start' ;
GRMR_END    : '!g end' ;

FILE_TYPE   : (V_CFGFILE|V_CLIFILEV1|YANGFILE) ;
V_CFGFILE   : 'v_cfg.dsl' ;
V_CLIFILEV1 : 'v_cliv1.dsl' ;
YANGFILE    : 'yang.dsl' ;
SEMICOLON   :  ';' ;
GTYPE_FILE  : 'gtype_file' ;` It is showing the graphical tree of parsed tokens.  But error in compile window: `line 3:0 missing SEMICOLON at '!g end'.  Sample in next..

Comment: `!g start
        gtype_file v_cfg.dsl ;
!g end
`   is the sample

Comment: any way to 'attach' files here?

Comment: if it is small, I think you can cut and paste. Otherwise you can use a "gist".